# Spotipy set redirect_uri

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy, redirect-uri

This is what I'm using right now to authenticate:

```
scope = "user-library-read"

SpotifyOAuth(client_id="9af97dea1d454457ae063fd20cb00740", client_secret="91baf6b3e5c44c71be017a136ac16a5f")
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope))
```

But it gives me this error:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: SpotifyOauthError: No redirect_uri. Pass it or set a SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI environment variable.

I tried setting the `redirect_uri` as an argument, but it says it's an unexpected keyword argument. Is there any way I can set the `redirect_uri` (without environment variables)?

Comment: The `redirect_uri` is an argument for the `SpotifyOAuth` constructor, you should pass it there instead of the `Spotify` constructor

Comment: You can see it listed in the [documentation for the SpotifyOAuth class](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.19.0/#spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a part of my code I use I know works:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
scope = "user-library-read"
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id="abcdef1234567890",client_secret="fedcba0987654321",redirect_uri="http://localhost:8080",scope=scope))
```

Comment: This gives me the error: 'Couldn't read cache at: .cache'